# printing memory address instead of data in java

Tags: arrays, memory-address, points

so i'm trying to setup an array that holds x y coordinates.
the program seems to work but my print results are memory addresses.
here's my code:

```
static class Point{
    int x;
    int y;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  x + " " + y;
    }
}

public static Object thePoints( int x, int y){
    Point[] mypoints = new Point[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < mypoints.length; i++){
       mypoints[i] = new Point();
    }   
    mypoints[0].x = 200;
    mypoints[0].y = 200;
    return mypoints;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Object thing = thePoints(0,0);

    System.out.print(thing);
    }
}
```

input is appreciated.

Comment: Your method returns an array of Points; that's the reference that's printed.  You need to iterate over it and call your toString() method for each Point in the array.  Why return an Object when you can return an array of Points?

Comment: @duffymo I reverted your recent edit because it changed the code in such a way that the original problem also changed.

Comment: Sorry, I got overzealous and edited your code after making format changes.  I think it works with the fixes.  Try it.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - right, I got carried away after reformatting.  I forgot where I was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing out an array of type `Point[]` in your `main()` method, contrary to what it appears.  A quick way to get around this problem is to use `Arrays.toString()`.  Try changing the code in your `main()` method to this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Object thing = thePoints(0,0);

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString((Point[])thing));
}
```

If you also refactor `Point.toString()` to the following, then you get some fairly nice looking output:

```
static class Point{
    int x, y;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";    // print out a formatted ordered pair
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[(200, 200), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
```

Comment: this almost works its telling me: no suitable method found cannot convert object to anything

Answer (score 0):

Your printing the 'Object thing' directly. System.out.print() only works on strings and primitive datatypes, so if you wanted to print information about the 'Object thing' you would have to use the toString() method you declared for the class 'Point'.

```
System.out.println(thing[0].toString());
```

Comment: Wrong - it works on any class that overrides toString() correctly.  Arrays don't.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism even if it was a wee bit rude :).

Comment: Rude?  You're too sensitive.

Comment: Lmao my inner head voice reads things differently I guess. The way I read it was like "Wrooooong -_- , this is how it actually works".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print an array of Point Objects which is why it prints out the memory address. You can use an ArrayList instead of an array. Printing an array list would call the toString method of each element which in you case is the toString method of Point Class.